# Recognizing pattern for 301 redirect in htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm migrating a legacy website to Wordpress.  The old site has over 15,000 posts,  but they are not consistent.  However they do have a pattern.

for e.g.

`How_Sri_Lanka_can_capitalize_on_the_Maritime_Silk_Road-3-3844-2.html`

could also appear as

`How_Sri_Lanka_can_capitalize_'on_the_Maritime_Silk_Road-3-3844.html`

I want to redirect this to a `redirect.php?oldid=3844`

The old URL format is

`[SOME_STRING_WITH_NUM]-3-POSTID.html`  or 
`[SOME_STRING_WITH_NUM]-3-POSTID-45.html` where `45` is an arbitrary number

In this example the 301 should redirect to `redirect.php?oldid=POSTID`

Any help is appreciated!  thank you!

I have tried redirecting everything ending with HTML extension which works but seems to throw up unexpected behavior in wordpress backend

Here's what I'm using in the .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#LEGACY URL Redirection 301

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .html$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ /redirect.php?old=$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you add few more variations of old post URLs in question.

Comment: Thank you,  sorry I missed this comment.   Here are more examples 

China_to_build_LNG_power_plant,_oil_refinery_and_dockyard_in_Hambantota-3-6915-4.html
Sri_Lanka_probes__suicide__by_alleged_killer_of_editor-3-6361-10.html
Sri_Lanka_recalls_assembly_as_flood_toll_nears_100-3-5059-13.html

Comment: Please click on edit link below the question and provide these examples. Also don't forget to mention their target redirected URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteBase /` line:

```
RewriteRule -\d+-(\d{2,})(?:-\d+)?\.html redirect.php?oldid=$1 [L,NE,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks,  this works in most cases but not when the URL pattern is like the following [SOME_STRING_WITH_NUM]-3-POSTID-45.html

Altetnatively,  If I get the entire Request URI,  I can process the ID in PHP

e.g. SOME_STRING_WITH_NUM]-3-POSTID.html or [SOME_STRING_WITH_NUM]-3-POSTID-45.html

In this case if i get redirect.php=[SOME_STRING_WITH_NUM]-3-POSTID-45.html

Comment: Can you write all example URLs for which it doesn't work. Click on edit link in question and provide all non-working URLs.

Comment: Thank you for following up, really appreciate this. You can test it here

http://economy.oddly.co/Sri_Lanka_s_MAS_Holdings_in_drive_to_boost_women_in_top_management-3-13902-13.html

This returns 13 ,  but should be 13902.  

This however works 
http://economy.oddly.co/MAS_Holdings_to_develop_wearable_menstruation_tech_for_Sri_Lankan_women-3-13937-4.html

But when you do two numbers at the end it takes those two numbers, instead of the id.

http://economy.oddly.co/MAS_Holdings_to_develop_wearable_menstruation_tech_for_Sri_Lankan_women-3-13937-44.html

it returns 44